# Embedding variables inside Apigee JSON payload

Tags: json, apigee

I want to return a JSON body inside an `AssignMessage`.

I found that if I write it as:
`<Payload>
{ "json":"json" }
</Payload>`

The `{` is interpreted as a variable. So I escaped it as 
`<Payload>
\{ "json":"json" }
</Payload>`

and the JSON payload comes out properly.

Now, I want to include a variable in the body, like `message.queryparam.xxx`.
I can't use `{}` anymore since the initial `{` was escaped.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by defining the variable delimiters.

```
<Payload contentType="application/json" variablePrefix="$" variableSuffix="%">
{
    "Key": "$variableName%"
}
</Payload>
```

Comment: Where does that block go inside AssignMessage?

Comment: @pulkitsinghal  for complete details of the AssignMessage policy schema follow documentation at http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/generate-or-modify-messages-using-assignmessage  It is available there.

Comment: I did! Since the trial & error afterwards took longer than any developer would like, here is a gist for everyone to peruse for getting a visual cue on what's placed where: https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/9350348

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with the variablePrefix and Suffix I just escape the first curlybrace as such:

```
<Payload contentType="application/json">
  \{
    "Key": "{variableName}"
  }
</Payload>
```

Don't escape the closing curlybrace or it will throw an error.